# onclick notification with clojurescript in firefoxos

Tags: onclick, clojurescript, firefox-os

i have this code to show a notification:

`(new js/Notification "call me" (clj->js {
        :onclick (js* "new MozActivity({name:'dial',number:'12345678'})")
        :sticky "true"
        :silent "true"
        :body (v "number")
        :icon "app://communications.gaiamobile.org/dialer/style/icons/dialer_84.png"}))`

The problem is the *onclick* function, without it, it shows correctly the notification. But if i leave it as stated it shows the dialing screen (?!?!?!?!)

i've tried also with

`:onclick (js/MozActivity. (clj->js {:name "dial" :data {:number "12345678"}}))`

and also behaves in the same manner

what is the correct way to pass a function to the onclick property of Notification?
`

Comment: The value you specify for the `:onclick` keyword needs to be a function that can be called later, by 'something else' when the users clicks. @Darwin's answer shows how. You could alternatively use `(fn [] (js/...)` to pass the function. The way you have it the function is being called much sooner than you want it to be.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy both your proposal and @Darwin 's one porduces a `null` value for onclick property :(

it's true it already doesn't fire the dialing screen, but it does nothing when i press over the notification :/

Comment: Yes the alternatives are the same thing so should yield the same result. The `fn` syntax just makes the difference between invoking and passing clearer IMHO. I imagine you copied the code from a working example somewhere. Can you post that up as well, or the links you used? So we can see the differences. Unfortunately I haven't needed to call js from cljs yet...

Comment: @ChrisMurphy No, i didn't copy the code anywhere. The code of the question is my real code and it behaves as i stated upper. You can test it yourself, if you have time. In regarding the :onclick i simply watched at the MDN documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification.

i didn't found an example of onclick Notification working in firefox ... because of that i posted my question here. Maybe a bug, i don't know :)

Comment: Seems to me a String is being passed into the world of js, but that String really needs to somehow be a reference to `new Moz...`. Could you just write the same js you would for a js `onclick` event? Perhaps @Darwin (and I) had the right idea but the wrong language!

Comment: well, as i said before i didn't see a working example of this in plain javascript, but the MDN documentation states that 
`Notification.onclick = function() { ... };` is what does the magic.

I'm wondering now if the problem is that i shouldn't pass the function when creating the object, but after it is created. But the truth is I don't know how to do that in clojurescript ....

Comment: Have you tried whatever this *actually* is in js: "function() {new MozActivity({name:'dial',number:'12345678'})}"?

Comment: should it be `:onclick (js* "function() {new MozActivity({name:'dial',number:'12345678'})}")` ?

i've tried that, but no way :S

Answer (score 0):

```
:onclick #(js/MozActivity. #js {:name "dial" :number "12345678"})
```